# Mostrar el nombre de la marca con un enlace con el plugin: Product Brands For WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

No sé si alguno ha usado este plugin, pero me gustaría mostrar el nombre de la marca debajo de la imagen de cada producto, pero no lo he conseguido.

¿Alguno sabe cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Buenas Jonhy, has probado alguna cosa? Pon el código para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Como dice @Marc, si nos muestras lo que has intentado podremos decirte qué tienes mal y como mejorarlo. Asi aprendes más que si te lo dieramos hecho. Recuerda mirar el [tour] y [ask] para aprender más de este sitio . un saludo

Comment: He usado un parte del código  <?php  $marcas = $product->get_brands(); 
        if ($marcas != '') { ?>
         <div class="brands2">
          <?php echo ''.$marcas;  ?>
         </div>
       <?php } ?>

Comment: La idea es que quiero aprender y mejorar mis conocimientos. Y tienen razón darmelo hecho, no tiene merito, pero si me ayudan a llegar a la respuesta mejor  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El plugin dispone de un Shortcode para mostrar la marca, simplemente debes localizar la plantilla del producto (single-product.php) y pegar esto donde quieras que aparezca en el HTML:

```
<?php do_shortcode(['pbf_wc]'); ?>
```

(No recuerdo si debería llevar el echo)

Al desconocer la plantilla que usas, no puedo darte una respuesta más concreta sobre la localización del fichero o donde debería ir en el código HTML.

Saludos,

Comment: La idea es mostrarlo de cada imagen del producto con php.

Comment: ¿Entiendo entonces, que te refieres a los listados de productos y no al single-product?

Comment: Sólo quiero mostrar el nombre de la marca debajo de cada producto.

Comment: Eso ya lo he entendido, pero quieres mostrarlo en los listados de productos (categorías) o el producto solo (single-product).

Comment: Quiero mostrarlo aquí https://ibb.co/ftEat6 y uso está plantilla https://themeforest.net/item/estore-modern-clean-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/19220873?s_rank=6

Comment: Esa captura no me ayuda para nada a identificar la sección donde quieres mostrarlo... es necesario saber la sección donde mostrarlo, por que requerirá de una programación u otra.

Comment: Quiero mostrar el nombre del producto en el listado de productos, es decir es un componente de jscomposer que puedo configurar el producto que quiera. 

Lo que quiero es que muestre el nombre de la marca del producto debajo de cada uno.